# C++ "Flipping" the rows in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, output

I am attempting to print out an array in a specific order, where it is formatted with columns and rows in ascending order, but with the bottom row containing the lowest values. The array is created via a for loop and a pointer. 
here is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    // Creation of the array
    int* array = new int[24];
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    // Displaying in grid format with 3 rows and 8 columns
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << *array << ' ';
            array++;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

The output of my code is:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

The desired output is:

```
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

How would I go about "reversing" the rows to reach the desired output?

SOLVED WITH THE FOLLOWING

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* table = new int[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
        table[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << table[j + (8 * i)] << ' ';
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) would be my goto solution.

Comment: The thing with std::reverse is that it reverses everything, so the top line of the output would change to 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16, but the desired result is to "reverse" just the rows.

Comment: Incrementing `array` is a bad idea since you need the original value to release the memory you allocated. Could you re-write your code using `i` and `j` as indices into `array` (so that `array` does not need to change values)?

Comment: @Joe Your edit **really** destroyed your program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Could you show an example of just the part that would need changed? I have not been able to get std::reverse to produce the desired result.

Comment: @Joe Ok. Concrete example: `int* array = new int[23];` and then `i < 24` which means that `array[23]` will be assigned. That is not a memory slot you've allocated.

Comment: It should be fixed now as far as that goes. I just forgot to change that line in my edit.

Comment: Don't update randomly. Have you thought this through? Now you have an array of `24` but you access `23` of the slots. Edit: better - the numbers align - but why 24, or 23 ... or 1324234? Pen and paper, draw what you try to do and come up with a solution that is agnostic with regards to the amount.

Comment: There are already plenty of examples all over internet for reversing arrays in C++. Same with creating a 2D array which would make sense for what you want to do.

Comment: @Joe The best "cheat" is to look at examples. As it happens, there is a good wiki page with examples and your problem just happens to be on display. Look at `Possible implementation` for [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: I feel like I am not communicating the desired output well. The output would not be the array reversed, but instead look like this:
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 \n 8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 \n 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
So the numbers are not just reversed, as it goes 23, 8, 9, ... 15, 0, 1...
If that makes sense

Comment: @Joe Those `\n`'s must feel awkward... :-) Sometime it's time to "not panic". Sleep on it. It's not worth banging your head against the wall when inspiration has run out. - 40 years of giving up and waking up with "aha" moments.

Comment: Your thing doesn't make sense as a 1D array. You need a 2D array

Comment: @OmidCompSCI  It looks like a nice 2d array mapped over a 1d allocation to me. Are you suggesting splitting it up? If so, for what purpose?

Comment: @Joe Just to not lead you astray. Your own 2D matrix is what people really do - with a few extras. You've got the basic part right - don't think otherwise. Every `new[]` needs a `delete[]`. Every `new` needs a `delete`. It's not harder than that (but that is hard enough). - but don't abandon  your 2D map over a 1D allocation though - that's really good.

Comment: I have solved it. The point of the exercise was to print like a 2D array without using a 2D array. I will clarify in the future. Sorry for wasting your time. It was just a simple mistake I made.

Comment: @Joe Please do not answer a question in the question. Post your answer as an answer. ([You can answer your own question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer))